# EF codefirst using MySqlConnector

Tags: .net, mysql, connector

When using the dotnetconnector from mysql for ado.net. I get the following problem as soon as i try to do more than 2 includes.

Error message: Object must implement IConvertible.

I looked on the internet and apparently it has something to do with the mysql driver. The problem is that they don't acknoledge it as a bug.

Can someone help me with an solution to rewrite the code given below so that it will work?

```
toSave = worker.Persons.Data.OfType<Employee>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == toCopyFrom.Id)
                .Include(x => x.PhoneNumbers)
                .Include(x => x.Contracts)
                .Include(x => x.Addresses)
                .Include(x => x.WorkAreas)
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Lazy loading is disabled because the json serializer can't work with it.